# JavaScript doesn't execute ajax call code sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, raphael

I am creating a gauge chart using `Raphael.js`.
I am using `ajax` to call a service that will return data that is to be shown in gauge chart.
My application has multiple HTML pages where this gauge chart should be shown, so I have created a common Layout HTML file for make chart code common.
I am using `MVC CSHTML` pages.

So the problem is, from the first HTML page when when I call the JavaScript code to generate gauge chart ajax code executes fine and returns data. But from another page all ajax part of the code just gets skipped and I have no data to bind in the gauge. And there is no error message in console also.

Here is the JS code for gauge generation:

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    debugger;
    var leadid = jQuery("#hdnSessionLeadId").data('value');
    var scoreNeeded = jQuery("#hdnscoreNeeded").data('value');
    var min = 0;
    var max = 0;
    var value = 0;
    var insurabilityScore = 0;
    var scoreAvg = 0;
    var description = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: "GaugeChartData?Lead_ID=" + leadid + "&Lob=Auto&scoreNeeded=" + scoreNeeded,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != "") {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                min = data.scoreMin;
                max = data.scoreMax;
                debugger;
                insurabilityScore = data.insurabilityScore;
                insurabilityScore = 700;
                description = 'Excellent';
                
                if (insurabilityScore == 0) {
                    description = '';
                    insurabilityScore = '';
                }
                else {
                    //description = data.description;
                }
                 scoreAvg = data.scoreAvg;
                 value = data.insurabilityScore;
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Got an Error');
        }
    });
    var config = {
        radius: 80,
        paddingX: 0,
        paddingY: 0,
        gaugeWidth: 15,

        fill: '0-#FE5249:5-#FA8B1B:12-#F8A903:20-#70CD60:90-#19C1E6:100-#19C1E6',
        gaugeBackground: '#f4f4f4',
        background: '#fff',

        showNeedle: true,
        showNeedles: true,
        animationSpeed: 1200,

        width: 200,
        height: 120,
        centerX: 0,
        centerY: 0,

        min: min,
        max: max,
        value: 0, 
        scoreAvg: scoreAvg,
        insurabilityScore: insurabilityScore,
        description: description,

        valueLabel: {
            display: true,
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            fontColor: '#1ABFE9',
            fontSize: '50',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            value: insurabilityScore,
        },
        valueLabel2: {
            display: true,
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            fontColor: '#1ABFE9',
            fontSize: '18',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            value: description,
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            value: 'Avg',
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            fontColor: '#000',
            fontSize: '10',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            centerX: 0,
            centerY: 0,
        },
        title2: {
            display: true,
            value: 'You',
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            fontColor: '#000',
            fontSize: '10',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            centerX: 0,
            centerY: 0,
        },
        label: {
            display: true,
            left: min,
            right: max,
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            fontColor: '#000',
            fontSize: '12',
            fontWeight: 'normal'
        }
    };

    // Create an arc with raphael.js
    Raphael.fn.arc = function (startX, startY, endX, endY, radius1, radius2, angle) {
        var arcSVG = [radius1, radius2, angle, 0, 1, endX, endY].join(' ');
        return this.path('M' + startX + ' ' + startY + ' a ' + arcSVG);
    };

    // Calculate a circular arc with raphael.js
    Raphael.fn.circularArc = function (centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
        var startX = centerX + radius * Math.cos(startAngle * Math.PI / 180);
        var startY = centerY + radius * Math.sin(startAngle * Math.PI / 180);
        var endX = centerX + radius * Math.cos(endAngle * Math.PI / 180);
        var endY = centerY + radius * Math.sin(endAngle * Math.PI / 180);
        return this.arc(startX, startY, endX - startX, endY - startY, radius, radius, 0);
    };


    // The kuma Gauge constructor
    function kumaGauge(element, options, method) {
        // This
        var _this = this;
        // The element
        _this.element = element;
        _this.$element = $(element);
        // The config
        _this.config = $.extend({}, config, options);
        _this._config = config;
        _this.method = method;
        // The actual gauge
        _this.gauge = {};
        // Initialize
        _this.init();
    }

    // Extend the kumaGauge object
    kumaGauge.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            // this
            _this = this;
            if (!_this.method) {
                _this.draw();
            }
        },
        _setup: function () {
            // This
            _this = this;
            // Calculate some values needed do draw the gauge
            _this.config.width = (_this.config.radius * 2) + (_this.config.paddingX * 2);
            _this.config.height = _this.config.radius + (_this.config.paddingY * 2);
            _this.config.centerX = _this.config.paddingX + _this.config.radius;
            _this.config.centerY = _this.config.paddingY + _this.config.radius;
            // The div which acts as the canvas needs an id, so we give it a unique one if it doesn't have one
            if (typeof $(this).attr('id') === 'undefined' || $(this).attr('id') === '') {
                _this.config.id = 'gauge-' + $('*[id^="gauge-"]').length;
                _this.$element.attr('id', _this.config.id);
            }
        },
        _calculateRotation: function (min, max, val) {
            var _range, _rotation;
            _range = max - min;

            if (val < max && val > min) {
                _rotation = 180 * ((val - min) / _range);
            } else if (val <= min) {
                _rotation = 0;
            } else {
                _rotation = 180;
            }

            return _rotation;
        },
        draw: function () {
            //this
            var _this = this;

            // Setup all the needed config variables
            _this._setup();

            // Make the base drawing Canvas
            _this.gauge = new Raphael(_this.config.id, _this.config.width, _this.config.height);

            // Draw the gauge
            _this.gauge.gauge = _this.gauge.circularArc(_this.config.centerX, _this.config.centerY,
                _this.config.radius, 180, 0);
            _this.gauge.gauge.attr({
                'fill': _this.config.fill,
                'stroke': 'none',
                'height':'120px'
            });
            _this.gauge.gauge.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge');

            // Draw the gauge background
            _this.gauge.gaugeBackground = _this.gauge.circularArc(_this.config.centerX, _this.config.centerY,
                _this.config.radius, 180, 0);
            _this.gauge.gaugeBackground.attr({
                'fill': _this.config.gaugeBackground,
                'stroke': 'none'
            });
            _this.gauge.gaugeBackground.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__background');

            // Draw the white center arc
            _this.gauge.centerArc = _this.gauge.circularArc(_this.config.centerX, _this.config.centerY,
                _this.config.radius - _this.config.gaugeWidth, 180, 0);
            _this.gauge.centerArc.attr({
                'fill': _this.config.background,
                'stroke': 'none'
            });
            _this.gauge.centerArc.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__center');
            _this.gauge.title2 = _this.gauge.text(_this.config.centerX - -50, _this.config.paddingY - -5,
                _this.config.title2.value);
            _this.gauge.title2.attr({
                'fill': '#55E5DA',
                'fill-opacity': 0,
                'font-size': _this.config.title2.fontSize,
                'font-family': _this.config.title2.fontFamily,
                'font-weight': _this.config.title2.fontWeight
            });
            
            //Draw the needle

            // Draw the bottom mask to hide the rotated background arc
            _this.gauge.bottomMask = _this.gauge.rect(0, _this.config.centerY, _this.config.width, 40);
            _this.gauge.bottomMask.attr({
                'fill': _this.config.background,
                'stroke': 'none'
            });

            // Draw the text container for the value
            if (_this.config.valueLabel.display) {
                
                    _this.gauge.valueLabel = _this.gauge.text(_this.config.centerX, _this.config.centerY - 30,
                        _this.config.insurabilityScore);
                
                _this.gauge.valueLabel.attr({
                    'fill': _this.config.valueLabel.fontColor,
                    'font-size': _this.config.valueLabel.fontSize,
                    'font-family': _this.config.valueLabel.fontColor,
                    'font-weight': _this.config.valueLabel.fontWeight
                });
                _this.gauge.valueLabel.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__value');
                _this.gauge.valueLabel.node.setAttribute('display', 'block');
            }
            // Draw the text container for the value
            if (_this.config.valueLabel2.display) {
                debugger;
                
                    _this.gauge.valueLabel2 = _this.gauge.text(_this.config.centerX, _this.config.centerY -0,
                        _this.config.description);
               
                _this.gauge.valueLabel2.attr({
                    'fill': _this.config.valueLabel2.fontColor,
                    'font-size': _this.config.valueLabel2.fontSize,
                    'font-family': _this.config.valueLabel2.fontColor,
                    'font-weight': _this.config.valueLabel2.fontWeight
                });
                _this.gauge.valueLabel2.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__value2');
                _this.gauge.valueLabel.node.setAttribute('display', 'block');
            }

            

            if (_this.config.label.display) {
                // Draw the left label
                _this.gauge.leftLabel = _this.gauge.text((_this.config.gaugeWidth / 2) + _this.config.paddingX + 2,
                    _this.config.centerY + 5, _this.config.label.left);
                _this.gauge.leftLabel.attr({
                    'fill': _this.config.title.fontColor,
                    'fill-opacity': 0,
                    'font-size': _this.config.label.fontSize,
                    'font-family': _this.config.label.fontFamily,
                    'font-weight': _this.config.label.fontWeight
                });
                _this.gauge.leftLabel.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__label--left');

                // Draw the right label
                _this.gauge.rightLabel = _this.gauge.text((_this.config.width - (_this.config.gaugeWidth / 2)) - _this.config.paddingX,
                    _this.config.centerY + 10, _this.config.label.right);
                _this.gauge.rightLabel.attr({
                    'fill': _this.config.title.fontColor,
                    'fill-opacity': 0,
                    'font-size': _this.config.label.fontSize,
                    'font-family': _this.config.label.fontFamily,
                    'font-weight': _this.config.label.fontWeight
                });
                _this.gauge.rightLabel.node.setAttribute('class', 'gauge__label--right');
            }
     
            setTimeout(function () {
                
                if (_this.config.title.display) {
                    _this.gauge.title.attr({
                        'fill-opacity': 1
                    });
                }
                if (_this.config.title2.display) {
                    _this.gauge.title2.attr({
                        'fill-opacity': 1
                    });
                }
                if (_this.config.label.display) {
                    _this.gauge.leftLabel.attr({
                        'y': _this.config.centerY + (_this.gauge.leftLabel.getBBox().height / 2),
                        'fill-opacity': 1,
                    });
                    _this.gauge.rightLabel.attr({
                        'y': _this.config.centerY + (_this.gauge.rightLabel.getBBox().height / 2),
                        'fill-opacity': 1,
                    });
                }
            }, 1000);
            // Animate the gauge to the right value position
            _this.gauge.gaugeBackground.animate({
                transform: 'r' +
                    _this._calculateRotation(_this.config.min, _this.config.max, _this.config.value) + ',' +
                    _this.config.centerX + ',' + _this.config.centerY
            }, _this.config.animationSpeed, '<>');

        },
        update: function (data) {
            //this
            var _this = this;
            var updateGauge = function (min, max, value) {
                _this.config.min = min;
                _this.config.max = max;
                _this.config.value = value;

                // Update the rotation of the gauge
                _this.gauge.gaugeBackground.animate({
                    transform: 'r' +
                        _this._calculateRotation(min, max, value) + ',' +
                        _this.config.centerX + ',' + _this.config.centerY
                }, _this.config.animationSpeed, '<>');

                // Update the value label
                if (_this.config.valueLabel.display) {
                    if (_this.config.showNeedle) {
                        _this.gauge.valueLabel.attr('text', value);
                    } else {
                        _this.gauge.valueLabel.attr('text', 500);
                    }
                }
            };

            if (typeof data.min !== 'undefined' && typeof data.max !== 'undefined' && typeof data.value !== 'undefined') {
                updateGauge(data.min, data.max, data.value);
            } else if (typeof data.value !== 'undefined') {
                updateGauge(_this.config.min, _this.config.max, data.value);
            }
        }
    };
    $.fn.kumaGauge = function (method, options) {
        var _method = method,
            _arguments = arguments,
            _this = this;
        if (typeof _method !== 'string') {
            if (_arguments.length === 1) {
                options = _method;
                method = false;

                return this.each(function () {
                    if (!$.data(this, 'kumaGauge')) {
                        $.data(this, 'kumaGauge', new kumaGauge(this, options, method));
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            return this.each(function () {
                if (typeof $.data(this, 'kumaGauge')[method] === 'function') {
                    $.data(this, 'kumaGauge')[method](options);
                }
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Chart generated on first page is shown in first picture.

[image]

Chart generated on second page is in the second Picture. As ajax call is not executed I have no data to show on this gauge chart so there is missing data.

[image]

The div section where gauge is generated:

```
<div class="js-gauge js-gauge--1 gauge scaling-svg"></div>
```

This is how function is called from document.ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   
    $('.js-gauge--1').kumaGauge({
        value: 1000,
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Obviously working AJAX code will not show the error. But WHY async=false? We need to see where you call this code and how often. Perhaps too often and you do not parse the return value before the next is called. Also look in the console for errors

Comment: I call the code from script tag of my HTML page. Its called on page load event. Its called one time for each  HTML Page.

Comment: then there is an error message in the console on page 2

Comment: I used async false to wait for the response from ajax call before executing next piece of code. If I dont use async false then code doesnt wait for ajax code to return data and executes next piece of code

Comment: There is no error message in console of page 2

Comment: Few points can be helpful for debugging, since we don't know your code structure:
1. Did you check the browser console or networks while executing this event?
1. Did you try to put some debug statements to print value of "leadid" and "scoreNeeded"?
2.Did you cross check the server logs if request is coming through?
3.Did you try to put a debug in error function of AJAX call?

Comment: Did you or some other script overwrite the page onload event on page2?

Comment: "I call the code from script tag of my HTML page. Its called on page load event. Its called one time for each HTML Page". Are you sure on this? try to check if that function is getting invoked or not.

Comment: @Nish there are no console or network issues. Leadid and scoreneeded have correct values. I just checked debugging the error function of ajax, no value. I didn't checked server logs

Comment: @Nish ajax call is the part of raphael.js file thet is generating the gauge curve. The curve is generated for second page but ajax call is not executed. Gauge generation and service call both are the part of one fie.

Comment: Then I guess, you need to recheck if your page load event is actually getting fired for the second HTML. This is just a hunch.

Comment: @Nish Its working because I am also generating a line chart also by calling function from page load event. Line chart appears fine on all the pages

Comment: @Nish I have added js code in the description. Please take a look

Comment: @mplungjan I have added js code in the description. Please take a look

Comment: Do you have values on page two of these? var leadid = jQuery("#hdnSessionLeadId").data('value');
    var scoreNeeded = jQuery("#hdnscoreNeeded").data('value');